# Mui material Breakpoints Error theme not finde

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, frontend

> Hi im try to place my code Breakpoints but in output show me error

```
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/styles";

const useStyle = makeStyles((theme)=>({
  LogoLg:{
    display:'none',
    [theme.breakpoints.up('sm')]:{
      display:'block'
    }
  }
}))

export default useStyle;
```

[image: this is error image]

Comment: According to MUI official docs, you cant simply return an object in makeStyle when you need to use the theme in it, 
you need to make a function call in your object as [here](https://mui.com/system/styles/basics/#stress-test)
and [here](https://mui.com/system/styles/basics/#using-the-theme-context)

Answer (score 1):

In the following stress test, you can update the theme color and the background-color property live:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: (props) => ({
    backgroundColor: props.backgroundColor,
    color: theme.color,
  }),
}));
```

## Using the theme context

Starting from v5, MUI no longer uses JSS as its default styling solution. If you still want to use the utilities exported by @mui/styles and they depend on the theme, you will need to provide the theme as part of the context. For this, you can use the ThemeProvider component available in @mui/styles, or, if you are already using @mui/material, you should use the one exported from @mui/material/styles so that the same theme is available for components from '@mui/material'.

```
import { makeStyles } from '@mui/styles';
import { createTheme, ThemeProvider } from '@mui/material/styles';

const theme = createTheme();

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    color: theme.palette.primary.main,
  }
}));

const App = (props) => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return <ThemeProvider theme={theme}><div {...props} className={classes.root}></ThemeProvider>;
}
```